# Spinner choice to be used across multiple activities

Tags: android, string, android-activity, textview, spinner

Having tried several of the methods suggested by other posts on this site I can only assume I'm thick, so if someone can have a glance over my code I would be grateful.

I have the selected item in a spinner in one activity and stored that item as a string, then passed the string to the next activity and displayed that in a 
Text View in that activity. That works a treat.

What I would like to do now is pass that string on to a third activity and display it in another Text View in the third activity.

To achieve this here is the code from my first activity after a button click.

`Intent recordissues2 = new Intent(RecordIssue.this, RecordIssue2.class);
        Bundle sitename = new Bundle();
        sitename.putString("txt1a",spinnerbuilding.getSelectedItem().toString());
        recordissues2.putExtras(sitename);
startActivity(recordissues2);`

And for the second activity in onCreate

`Bundle sitename = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String txt1a = sitename.getString("txt1a");
        ((TextView) findViewById(Sitelbl2)).setText(txt1a);`

if you can help me with some example code to achieve the next step and where it should go and preferably exactly how it is working that would be perfect.

Thank you in advance.
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use shared preferences to store data and use them throughout the application in any activity class:

```
    SharedPreferences myprefs= this.getSharedPreferences("shared_key", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    myprefs.edit().putString("spinner_value", value).commit();
```

You can retrieve this info across your app like this:

```
    SharedPreferences myprefs= getSharedPreferences("shared_key", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String spinner_value= myprefs.getString("spinner_value", null);
```

Comment: Thanks, Its like I'm missing something, There is obviously a gap in my limited knowledge because when I use your code, it tells me it "cannot resolve symbol 'value' " So having never 'value' I realise I must change it but to what? I have put the code in the on click event but before the intent to move to next event, maybe that's wrong I'm not sure.

Comment: no problem,,,here value= spinnerbuilding.getSelectedItem().toString(); the spinner value you want to save ...if it works can you please accept the answer

Comment: Well I used your code and it gave me enough understanding to make the changes required to make it work.

Comment: Here are the changes I used:

Comment: First Activity: 'SharedPreferences myprefs= this.getSharedPreferences("shared_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myprefs.edit();
        editor.putString("spinner_value", spinnerbuilding.getSelectedItem().toString());
        editor.apply();'             And Second activity ' SharedPreferences myprefs= getSharedPreferences("shared_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String spinner_value = myprefs.getString("spinner_value","");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvbuilding)).setText(spinner_value);'

Answer (score 0):

In your `RecordIssue2` activity, you have already stored your text as `txt1a`. Using the same concept, add it to your `Intent`'s bundle when navigating to the third activity.

```
Intent recordissues3 = new Intent(RecordIssue2.this, RecordIssue3.class);
Bundle sitename = new Bundle();
sitename.putString("txt1a",txt1a);
recordissues3.putExtras(sitename);
startActivity(recordissues3);
```

Comment: Thanks but as with the above reply I get  "cannot resolve symbol 'txt1a'"  where "sitename.putString("txt1a",IS ROBLEM)"

Comment: You should do it after `Bundle sitename = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String txt1a = sitename.getString("txt1a");
        ((TextView) findViewById(Sitelbl2)).setText(txt1a);` in the second activity so that `txt1a` is already defined, probably in the onClick of a button.

Comment: Hi there, I have accepted another answer but if you look at my other question and post this solution there I have asked how its done without the use of sharedprefs and as your solution does actually work I will mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem, as long as your problem has been solved.